# Which 2018-2020 sets are good for roof parts?

Tags: sets, slope

What 2018-2020 sets are best for roof parts, such as corner slopes, 2x2 slopes, 2x4 slopes, etc.?

Comment: Just out of interest, why only 2018-2020 sets?

Comment: @bryantp26 I think OP's preference is chose from sets that are still fresh and widely available.

Comment: @Alex OK. thanks!

Comment: yes I'm looking for sets available on stores. Because giving bricklink order from another country is taking too much time because of covid related situations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest to look into buying [individual parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=31) on Bricklink in desired color, shape and amount. Any other set you can buy most likely won't have all the parts you need and you are left with otherwise unnecessary elements.

If you really need a set with roof specific parts, the set I could think of now is [Emmet's Dream House/Rescue Rocket (70831)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70831-1). Selection of slopes isn't ideal and color (blue) may not fit your need, however the amount of specific items is substantial compared to other sets. [Newbury Haunted High School (70425)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70425-1) could also be a candidate for some number of slopes, but it is still rather limited.

Alternatively, you could look into creating your roof without using slopes. Take a looks at sets like [31078](https://brickset.com/sets/31078-1/Tree-House-Treasures), [75954](https://brickset.com/sets/75954-1/Hogwarts-Great-Hall), [10267](https://brickset.com/sets/10267-1/Gingerbread-House). You can build your roof with plates and tiles if used wisely.

Comment: I've bought thousands of slope pieces on bricklink. This is definitely the way to go.  There aren't many sets that have more than a handful of slope pieces.  When you get into more obscure colors like dark purple it is even more difficult to do this through parting out sets.  However, with bricklink you can corner the world market in an hour or so.  Bru-hahahahaha. ;-)

Comment: Yes I know bl is way to go but, since world is changing because of covid-19, it became more and more painful to get packages from another country, at least in my country. So thats why I'm asking especially for sets available on market.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get them from [LEGO pick-a-brick](https://www.lego.com/de-de/page/static/pick-a-brick?query=roof) searching for "roof" gives you quite a collection, but misses the ends and corners that are available, so add another search for "45°" to get them.

Combine this with Bricklink and buy whereever it is cheaper or where you can find the wanted quantities of desired elements.

Comment: unfortunately we don't have pick-a-brick in Turkey except LEGO Stores. And it is not allowed to hand pick items since when pandemic started.

Comment: In Germany, the pick-a-brick in the stores is now handled by the personal: They have a display of available pieces and you can ask for them by their code (like 'E6'). Works well.